# How to store and get datetime value in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

My table contains Birthdate field which  has datatype as datetime.
I want to get all records having birthday today.
  How can I get it?

Answer (score 7):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE strftime('%m-%d', 'now') = strftime('%m-%d', birthday)
```

Comment: What is the datatype? Is it `TEXT`? Or maybe `BLOB`? It would be helpful if the docs said what to use for `sqlite3_bind_xxxx`. And I would be curious to know if other operators, like `>=`, work as expected. Also see [SQLite binding function in prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9497258/608639).

Answer (score 5):

Having a special datetime type has always seemed like unnecessary overhead to me, integers are fast, flexible, and use less space.

For general datetime values use Unix Epoch timestamps.  Easy to work with, extremely flexible, as well as timezone (and even calender!) agnostic.  (I recently wrote [an article on using them, which I really have to plug...](http://lost.co.nz/main/programming/epoch.html))

That said, if you're only interested in dates in the Gregorian calendar you may want to use a large integer in the following format: YYYYMMDD, eg 19761203.  For you particular usage you could even create a four digit integer like MMDD, say 1703 — that's got to result in fast selects!

Comment: It looks like SQLite can store dates as a unix time: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html (See "1.2 Date and Time Datatype"). So no wasted space there.

Comment: As for storing your date as an integer like YYYMMDD, what about birthdays that do have dates? What about birthdays in the same month? There's a lot of mod/div operations required to pull out each date fragment. Seems to me that you'd be better off using the database's built-in (and optimized and readable) tools like NickD's answer.

Answer (score 4):

SQLite has very poor support for storing dates. You can use the method suggested by Nick D above but bear in mind that this query will result in full table scan since dates are not indexed correctly in SQLite (actually SQLite does not support dates as a built-in type at all).

If you really want to do a fast query then you'll have to add a separate (integral) column for storing the birth day (1-31) and attach an index for it in the database.

If you only want to compare dates then you can add a single (INTEGER) column that will store the date UTC value (but this trick won't allow you to search for individual date components easily).

Good Luck

Comment: DATE or DATETIME would be stored as NUMERIC (see "2.2 Affinity Name Examples" in http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) as a unix time (see section "1.2 Date and Time Datatype"). Storing the day and month is a possible optimization, storing another INTEGER column is redundant.