# SQLite binding function in prepared statement

Tags: c, sqlite, date, binding, insert

I've problem with binding current date. I want to use `datetime('now')` function as one of inserted value.

I've used something like this:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, i + 1, values[i], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

where `values[i]` is `char * text = datetime('now')`. But obviously it inserts that text. Is there possibility to bind function like that: `datetime('now')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding, by definition, nicely escapes everything and makes sure everything is a string that the SQL interpreter doesn't actually misread as an SQL component.  It's a data safety issue.

Instead, make your `stmt` variable put the datetime('now') directly where it should be in the original SQL expression. IE, remove the related `?` and put `datetime('now')` in its place.